How to create aws cluster with infrastructure as ec2 and asg using aws cli
In the AWS online UI, when creating a cluster, a user can select these additional options:

Infrastructure:

Amazon EC2 instances

Auto Scaling group: Create new ASG|select
Provisioning model: On-demand|Spot
Container instance Amazon Machine Image: Amazon Linux image etc.
EC2 instance type: t2.micro
EC2 instance role: Create New Role|Select
Desired capacity: min: 0, max 5 etc.
SSH Key pair:




Networking settings:

VPC:
Subnets:
Security Group:



When using the terminal - aws cli, the options are limited for creating a cluster.
See example:
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/2.3.2/reference/ecs/create-cluster.html
It is not possible to select most of these other options via the aws create-cluster command. At the very least I want to be able to select EC2 and ASG.
How is this typically done via aws cli?
What other commands would I need to run in aws-cli to replicate what the UI "Create Cluster" does?
My end goal is to push docker images to aws ec2 using aws-cli commands only, before moving onto other orchestration tools.
I don't need specific implementation details. Just the core steps.
ie

create-cluster
create task definition
what's next and in what order?

I have so far followed the instructions:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/getting-started-cli.html
Step 1 - step 7.
I cannot find anymore tutorials in AWS documentation to describe my intentions above.

ok after a lot of debugging and tutorials (none of which are complete) I've established a working model of steps.
Pre-requisite:
Run and test local Dockerfile for single nginx hello world example
Folder directory
/deployScripts 
  ..scripts here...
/project_name/
  DockerFile etc...

Disclaimer
This tutorial also is not complete because you are going to have to supply the variables as below.
Also you will need to configure your current aws user login to have the permission for the following commands. This won't be too hard to discover because every command you follow below will give an error message to say you need that permission. You can simply go to your configured login permission and add them one by one. Eventually your permission will look something like this (not complete).
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:CreateRepository",
                "iam:PassRole", # You need this on for below roles: ecsTaskRole and ecsTaskExecutionRole to be defined below >
...ADD YOUR PERMISSION HERE...
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}


cd deployScripts



Create-Repository.sh

aws ecr create-repository --repository-name "${project_name}" > /dev/null



Push.sh

cd deployScripts
aws ecr get-login-password --region ${region}|docker login --username AWS --password-stdin --password-stdin $accountID.dkr.ecr.$REGION.amazonaws.com
docker build -t ${project_name} ../${project_name}
docker tag ${project_name} ${imageFullTAG}
docker push ${imageFullTAG}



create-cluster.sh

aws ecs create-cluster --cluster-name $project_name



Create-security-groups.sh

#!/bin/sh

securityGroupID=$(aws ec2 create-security-group --group-name $securityGroupName --description "Security group for docker" --vpc-id $vpcID | jq -r '.GroupId')

# windows. Use alternative command for linux
myip=$(curl ifcfg.me)

# ssh from my ip
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $securityGroupID \
    --protocol tcp \
    --port 22 \
    --cidr $myip/32

## https from anywhere
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $securityGroupID \
    --protocol tcp \
    --port 443 \
    --cidr 0.0.0.0/0

## http from anywhere
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress \
    --group-id $securityGroupID \
    --protocol tcp \
    --port 80 \
    --cidr 0.0.0.0/0



Run EC2 instance and associate with cluster

user-data.template
#!/bin/bash
echo ECS_CLUSTER=$project_name >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config

Run-instance-associate-with-cluster.sh
#!/bin/sh

amiID=$(aws --profile default ssm get-parameter --name ' /aws/service/ecs/optimized-ami/amazon-linux-2/recommended/image_id' | jq -r '.Parameter.Value')

vpcID=$(aws ec2 describe-vpcs | jq -r '.Vpcs[].VpcId')
# subnets=$(aws --profile default ec2 describe-subnets --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-0eb5674ddf242dea3" | jq -r '[.Subnets[] | select(.Tags[]?.Value) .SubnetId] | join(" ")')

subnetID=$(aws --profile default ec2 describe-subnets --filters "Name=vpc-id,Values=${vpcID}" | jq -r '[.Subnets[] | select(.MapPublicIpOnLaunch==true) .SubnetId][0]')


# Create user-data.txt file
envsubst < ./user-data.template > ./user-data.txt

instanceID=$(aws ec2 run-instances \
  --profile default \
  --image-id $amiID \
  --count 1 \
  --instance-type t2.micro \
  --iam-instance-profile Name=ecsInstanceRole \
  --key-name $keypair \
  --security-group-ids $securityGroupID \
  --subnet-id $subnetID \
  --user-data file://user-data.txt \
  --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=nginx-instance}]' \
  | jq -r '.Instances[] | .InstanceId')

echo "Created instace for cluster: instanceID=${instanceID}"



create-log-group.sh

aws logs create-log-group --log-group-name $project_name



Create both roles which have same permissions


ecsTaskExecutionRole
ecsTaskRole

trust relationship
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
         "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}

policy
AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role

Create role (this is not declared in task-definition but still needed)


ecsInstanceRole

trust relationship
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
         "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}

policy

AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role



Create Task definition

task-definition.template
{
  "family": "$project_name",
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "EC2"
  ],
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::$accountID:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::$accountID:role/ecsTaskRole",
  "networkMode": "bridge",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "name": "$project_name",
      "image": "$imageFullTAG",
      "cpu": 128,
      "memoryReservation": 256,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "options": {
          "awslogs-create-group": "true",
          "awslogs-group": "$project_name",
          "awslogs-region": "$region",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ],
      "essential": true,
      "healthCheck": {
        "command": [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -f http://localhost/ || exit 1"
        ],
        "interval": 10,
        "retries": 3,
        "startPeriod": 0,
        "timeout": 5
      }
    }
  ]
}

Create-task-definition.sh
#!/bin/sh
envsubst < ./task-definition.template > ./task-definition.json
export taskDefinitionArn=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://task-definition.json | jq -r '.taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn')
echo "Created Task Definition: ${taskDefinitionArn}"



create-service.sh

#!/bin/sh
serviceArn=$(aws ecs create-service \
--cluster $project_name \
--service-name $project_name \
--task-definition $taskDefinitionArn \
--desired-count 1 \
--launch-type EC2 | jq -r '.service .serviceArn')

echo "Created serviceArn=${serviceArn}"

Visit the Public IPv4 DNS of the in AWS > EC2 > 'nginx-instance'
done!
Conclusion.
The original answer as not to use aws cli commands because it isn't typically done this way. Alternatives are to use the AWS console or terraform or potentially ecs-cli, but how do you really learn the low level details if you do that? A lot of the terminology and steps are hidden. My steps above maybe able to refine a little more but I had lots of hurdles to get that to work.
Notes:
The main problems I had were following tutorials that weren't complete. For example including the image tag in the taskdefinition.json I added the shortcut name and that continously failed for me. I had to add the full image tag as it is pushed onto aws. Also this is an easy mistake and will lose you days - you need 3 roles: ecsTaskRole, ecsTaskExecutionRole AND ecsInstanceRole, and when declaring in aws cli you also have to create instance profile of same name.

The UI is doing many AWS API calls for you when you use that interface. Using the CLI you would have to run separate CLI commands for each of those AWS API calls. For example just to create the load balancer, you would have to execute quite a few aws elbv2 calls to create the load balancer itself, its target group, configure listeners on the load balancer, assign an SSL certificate to the load balancer, etc.

How is this typically done via aws cli?

The AWS CLI is typically not used to create your entire infrastructure like this. While it is certainly possible to use the CLI to do this, there are just much better tools available. I usually only see the AWS CLI used for automating the creation of a single S3 bucket or something, not an entire server cluster with load balancers and everything else that goes with it.
Typically, when people are trying to automate their infrastructure creation, they will use an Infrastructure as Code (IaC) tool, such as CloudFormation, or Terraform. There are also Cloud Development Kits (CDKs) available that allow you to write code in the programming language you prefer, that generate the CloudFormation or Terraform templates for you.
IaC tools also give you the benefits of managing the changing state of your infrastructure over time, and providing drift detection.

Thankyou for your reply.  I understand that the UI create cluster is doing many things in the background which the aws-cli create-cluster command is not. The reason for my question is to discover the  aws-cli commands to use after create-cluster to replicate what the ui does. My end goal is to push docker images to aws ec2 using the terminal - preferably aws-cli, because I want to understand the steps. CloudFormation is AWS specific and hides complexity of those steps and Terraform is Cloud provider agnostic so also hides AWS specific steps. I can use them later. My question is on the cli.

Terraform doesn't hide AWS specific steps. You would use the AWS provider for Terraform, and create AWS resources in Terraform HCL templates. Those individual resources which would map almost one-to-one to the AWS API endpoints, or AWS CLI commands, that would be needed to create all these resources. But Terraform is going to understand the dependencies and creating things in the correct order for you, and make it easy to connect the resources together by allowing them to reference each other. Doing that through the CLI requires a lot more work.

Terraform is a wrapper which I have to learn on top of aws logic. In anycase, its not my question.

Your question is how is this "typically" done, and that is what my answer addresses.
